# Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z+1)}$ in the annulus $0 < |z| < 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am asked to compute the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z+1)}$ in the annulus $0 < |z| < 1$.

The only examples I have seen of computing a Laurent series expansion is by rewriting the above function to look like a geometric series using partial fraction decomposition. In this particular example, we have,

$$ \frac{1}{z(z-1)(z+1)} = - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2(z-1)} + \frac{1}{2(z+1)}$$

Rewriting this,

$$ - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z} \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{z}} + \frac{1}{2z} \frac{1}{1 - (-\frac{1}{z})}$$

$$= - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z} \sum \left ( \frac{1}{z} \right)^n + \frac{1}{2z} \sum \left (- \frac{1}{z} \right)^n$$

However, the summations only converge for $|z| > 1$ and thus will not converge inside of the given annulus.

What do I do in this case?

Comment: Write
$$-\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - z} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1 - (-z)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $z^2-1=(z-1)(z+1)$,
$$
\frac{1}{z (z-1)(z+1)}=-\frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{1-z^2}=1+z^2+z^4+\cdots
$$
for $0 <|z|<1$.